# CSS Height of div and Angular UI Routing

Tags: html, css, angularjs

First Problem: Move one square, so the border shows up. Then open up menu. It does not cover the whole height and I already tried for 2 hours to fix it. ( It should at least fill the whole height, but preferable also be vertically centered)

Second Problem: Make your window height small. You will see the menu shows up, but when the drawing loads it pushes the menu outta view. I'd prefer the menu to in view. always.

Comment: Hi @muhkuhso and welcome to SO. Please add a code snippet to your question so it is still valid if your website changes. :)

Comment: From Menu class remove position:absolute

Comment: @Reena : I'm aifraid this might not be a good idea -> How to hide the menu then? Furthermore it is icon-menu class which troubles me (i should prob give them better names..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, for your first Issues you will need to set height 100% to html & body just like as follows.

```
html, body {
  height:100%;
}
```

I did not understood your second problem.

Comment: Oh my god. Of course i added height:100% to nearly everthing while trying to figure out the problem.. body e.g. but it didn't came to my mind to simply add it to html. Shame on me. Thank you so much!

Comment: It happens some time, we misses simple things and eventually ends up with something nonsense

Comment: For the second problem, free free to take a look at this image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13720935/150715soprob1.png The drawing div pushes the menu out of view when the window is too small.

Comment: It is not happening at my end, may be it is a cross browser issue.  or you can try adding left: 0; and top: 0; properties to your ".icon-menu" class

Comment: Already tried
  left:  0;
  top:  0;
  z-index: 9;
didn't helped too bad.

I can reproduce this on newest IE,FF,Chrome and on my Androids default Chrome.


Loading Page. Resizing Window -> Fine

You have to reload the page after you've resized the window. The Menu at first is where it should be but then when the drawing is loaded, it kinda "pushes" the menu away. (It come back to view when you increase your windows height again..)

Comment: Okay, Now I am able to produce this bug at my end. while solving this I am changing position : fixed to ".icon-menu" class, and it is working for me, can you please try and implement it in your code. I am not 100% sure about it though.

Comment: It solves this one but creates some new problems: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13720935/150715soprob2.png
(again not full height and the X to close went missing. Logic consequence.. same cause as with the "Menu" But if i set the X also so fixed I can't move it out of sight. But prob. i can .hide it... gonna play aroud now and google for a good explanation of the differences of static, fixed,sticky,absolute,relative..)

Comment: Maybe I better just stick with higher window size and/or smaller content ;-)

Comment: position: fixed should be applied to ".icon-menu" only and not to ".menu" or to X,

Comment: Yeah, I did understand you and did exactly this. But as a logical consequence when the "Menu" was pushed to top out of view ... also the Menu itself (X and Home/About etc..) was pushed out of view.. but before there was no way to open the menu and see it. Now there is. And of course it is has the same problem. live right now.

Comment: Humm.. I tried position:fixed with menu aswell. and its getting 100% height to the menu container.

Comment: Shame on me again. I found my error. It seems to work perfectly now with just those two changes.